# How to split the following string using Java?

Tags: java, string, split, hashmap

How do I go about splitting the following string using Java?

```
{525={174=2, 133=1, 182=1}}
```

There can be multiple lines similar to above. Each of them is a  combination for the outer HashMap. 
Assuming there is another line

```
{500={100=2, 150=1, 200=1}}
```

The desired structure would be

```
525 -> 174 -> 2
       133 -> 1
       182 -> 1
500 -> 100 -> 2
       150 -> 1
       200 -> 1
```

I want to have the numbers in a Hashmap>.

Here is what I tried:

```
String s="{525={174=2, 133=1, 182=1}}";
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> fullMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>();
Integer key, innerKey, innerValue;
key = Integer.parseInt(s.split("=")[0].replace("{",""));
```

I'm new to Java and don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Can you show the keys and values you'd expect in the HashMap for the input "{525={174=2, 133=1, 182=1}}"?

Comment: 525 would be the key for the fullMap, 174, 133, 182 would be the keys for the inner map and 2,1,1 would be the values for those respectively.

There can be more strings like the one above. Those would be the other keys and values of fullMap.

Comment: Please provide the *syntax* for the input string, and an explanation of how you want it to be split.  A single example is not a proper requirements specification.

Comment: Is this always going to be for list(s) within a list (i.e. no more than two lists deep)? Or could it be deeper? If so, you're going to have to carefully count `{` and `}` (basically code a pushdown automaton).

Comment: That's kind of like JSON format, and you have nesting.  It can't be reasonably represented in a "flat" Map.

Comment: So if this is kind of like JSON, can't you just use actual JSON?

Comment: OK - so two examples is better than one.  But this is still not a syntax specification.  What about whitespace.  Where is it allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
    String[] a = s.replaceAll("[{}]", "").split("=", 2);
    int key = Integer.parseInt(a[0].trim());
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String e : a[1].split(",")) {
        a = e.split("=");
        innerMap.put(Integer.parseInt(a[0].trim()),  Integer.parseInt(a[1].trim()));
    }
    fullMap.put(key, innerMap);
```